# Can I update my [rooted] phone using downloaded OTA zip file? how?

Tags: updates, root-access, ota-update, htc-one

My phone (HTC One M7) is rooted, so I can't update it simply by accepting update option in the settings menu.

I downloaded a zip file from a forum for an OTA available for my phone.

Now how can I use this OTA zip file to update my phone? How can I do that?

My phone:
HTC One M7, rooted, bootloader unlocked, S-on.

thanks.

Comment: If you downloaded it, it's not an OTA update. OTA means it's downloaded and installed directly on the device. It's just an update.

Comment: this is the file I've got: http://www.htc1guru.com/2014/05/sense-6-5-11-401-10-ota-file/ I am assuming these guys some how GRABBED the ota and made a zip file out of it. still the question is how to install it?

Answer (score 1):

These OTA files check for every part(file) of the update if a checksum still matches. If your rooting procedure touched some files on the system partition or you removed some preinstalled files this check will fail and the updating procedure will stop because of an assertion error.

As you already found out you need to restore your system partition to the expected state inside the OTA update(matching checksums) install the update via recovery and re-root as this procedure deletes all changes not included in the OTA update package from your system partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already downloaded the zip file then you need to flash it via `recovery mode` using a custom recovery.

You usually get to this by holding `power`+ `down` on HTC devices.

Custom recoveries like TWRP can also reinstall root if it is lost during the update process.

Comment: ok, I already have TWRP recovery flashed. Should I reboot to the "fastboot" mode, connect phone to computer via USB and run the flashing command? what is the command, is it "fastboot flash OTA_file.zip" ? Could you please elaborate? I am newbie, I have been reading about these stuff for several days, but still did not figures it out :s

Comment: Stay in recovery mode. If you go to Advanced > ADB Sideload you can flash the update using the command adb sideload OTA_file.zip

Comment: adb sideload OTA_file.zip did not work. it says: error. No details. (and yes, adb is connected, I try adb services first and it returns the phone model). I am gonna try copying the OTA file in phone and try installing it via TWRP install menue.

Comment: Cool, let us know how you get on

Comment: 1990clb, It started the update process, but did not go though.  In the middle process was canceled because of some PRELOAD apk files. I googled and appears this is an error with some models (even non rooted), or maybe it is just because my  phone was rooted! I dunno. I ended up flashing a stock rom, updating OTA, and then re-rooting.